# Previous GET parameters being unintentionally preserved in POST request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

As of current I navigate to a view using a GET request, looking something like this:

*/batches/install?Id=2&ScheduledDate=07.29%3A12*

From there, I send a POST request using a form (where I include what data I wish to include in the request.

Furthermore I set the forms action to "Create" which is the action I wish to send the request to.

My issue is the fact that sending this request keeps the GET arguments in the POST url, making it look the following:

*../batches/Create/2?ScheduledDate=07.29%3A12*

I do not want this since:

1: it looks weird

2: it sends data I do not intend it to send in this request

3: if my model already has a property named "id" or "scheduledDate" the unintentional GET parameters will get bound to those properties.

How can I ignore the current GET parameters in my new POST request?
I just want to send the form POST data to the url:
../batches/create
(without any GET parameters)

How would this be done?

As requested, here is my POST form:

```
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form("Create")))
{
  //inputs omitted for brevity

    @Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Style(ButtonStyle.Success).Text("Create batch")
}
```

Note that I use the TwitterBootstrapMVC html helpers (https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/), althought this really shouldn't matter.

As requested, to sum up:

**I send a get request to : /batches/install?Id=2&ScheduledDate=07.29%3A12.**

**Through the returned view I send a POST request to: /batches/create.**

**However the previous get parameters get included in the POST request URL making the POST request query: /batches/Create/2?ScheduledDate=07.29%3A12 (which is NOT intended).**

Comment: Please show the HTML or Razor for the form from where your POST request gets fired.

Comment: @lbrahim
I have included the basic form in my question.

Comment: Not clear what your asking. If your posting a form you should be redirecting to another GET method so that there would be no parameters . Alternatively, if your returning the view to correct validation errors then why would you expect

Comment: @StephenMuecke
The scenario is:
I send a get request to : /batches/install?Id=2&ScheduledDate=07.29%3A12. Through the returned view I send a POST request to: /batches/create , however the previous get parameters get included in the POST request URL making the POST request query: /batches/Create/2?ScheduledDate=07.29%3A12 (which is NOT intended.).

Comment: What you see in the address bar of a browser is query string parameters generated as a result of a GET (not a POST). You need to show your POST method to understand what you are really doing

Comment: @StephenMuecke
I'm simply posting some data through a form (as included in my question). Pardon me for asking but what else do you want me to include?

The issue is simply that I do not want the current GET parameters to be included in the new POST request being sent from the view.

Comment: Your POST method should be redirecting which means you will immediately see a different url in the address bar so its unclear what your actually saying.

Comment: @StephenMuecke
I will redirect it, however is there any way to remove the GET parameters being sent with the POST request? I only wanna send the POST arguments (not the GET arguments from the previous request).

Comment: It's not clear what you saying. The query string parameters will always be 'posted' (along with form data, route values etc) but you don't 'see' them - there is no 'post request url' as such. You wont show your post method so can't help any further.

Comment: @JensOlsen112  `/batches/Create/2?ScheduledDate=07.29%3A12` The querystring aside, how is `2` getting into your POST action url after `Create`? Because according to your form code above it should send form data to `/batches/create`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great Idea though, but will give you what you want.

```
[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create() {
      //do whatever you want with the values
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "batches");
 }
```

Comment: Yea I kind of thought of that myself as well, but I would like to avoid performing an unnecessary redirect for such a seemingly simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "Feature" of MVC that was previously reported as a bug ([issue 1346](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346)). As pointed out in the post, there are a few different workarounds for it:

> 1. Use named routes to ensure that only the route you want will get used to generate the URL (this is often a good practice, though it won't help in this particular scenario)
> 2. Specify all route parameters explicitly - even the values that you want to be empty. That is one way to solve this particular problem.
> 3. Instead of using Routing to generate the URLs, you can use Razor's ~/ syntax or call Url.Content("~/someurl") to ensure that no extra (or unexpected) processing will happen to the URL you're trying to generate.

For this particular scenario, you could just explicitly declare the parameters with an empty string inside of the Form.

```
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form("Create").RouteValues(new { Id = "", ScheduledDate = "" })))
{
    //inputs omitted for brevity

    @Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Style(ButtonStyle.Success).Text("Create batch")
}
```